# A question on piecewise continuity

Tags: calculus

Let us say a function $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on an closed and bounded interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is piecewise continuous on $I$ if there exists a partition of $I$ (i.e., numbers $x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_{n+1},$ for some natural number $n,$ such that $I = \cup_{j=1}^n[x_{j-1},x_j] $) such that $f|(x_j,x_{j+1})$ is **uniformly** continuous on $(x_j,x_{j+1})$ for each $j = 0,\cdots, n.$

Show that $f(x)$ defined as below is **not** piecewise continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

$$
f(x) = x \mathrm{sgn} \sin(x^{-1}), \hspace{1cm} x\neq 0, \hspace{1cm} f(0) = 0.
$$
Here $\mathrm{sgn}$ stands for the signum function that returns $+1$ for positive arguments, $-1$ for negative arguments, and $0$ when $x = 0.$

Comment: A piecewise continuous function can have only finitely many discontinuities.

Comment: Pick a partition of $\Bbb{R}$ into finitely many intervals. One of the intervals must contain $0$ or $0$ must be one if its endpoints. The problem is that $f$ is not continuous in any neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Can you please add some details as to why that is true. If $(-\delta,\delta)$ is a neighborhood of $0,$ then for any $\epsilon > 0,$ we see $|f(x)| \leq |x|\cdot 1 < \epsilon $ if $\delta = \epsilon,$ which seems to suggest that $f$ is continuous on this neighborhood, and hence uniformly continuous on any compact subset of it. What's the error in this argument?